# Where is the kernel weight initialization in CNN model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I build a CNN model based on this code: https://github.com/MesSem/CNNs-on-CHB-MIT/blob/master/CNN.py 
I know that in deep learning you have to initialize weights for optimization of the neural network.
This site https://keras.io/initializers/ in Keras clearly indicates the use of a `kernel_initializer` for weight initialization. However, I do not see any `kernel_initializer`.

I want to find the initial weights in the code.Anyone who can provide some insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Keras layers use `glorot_uniform` by default (eg [Conv](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L111) example here).

This initializer uses random weights sampled from uniform distribution with a range that depends on sum of input and output dimensions (as far as I remember, the range is `+/-sqrt(6/(input_dim + output_dim))`.

Here is a link to the paper, if you're interested to learn the concept in depth: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.
I didn't find `glorot_uniform` in the code or any other initializer.I don't know where is the weight initialization in the code.

Comment: @gigi https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops_v2.py#L545-L571 actual implementation is in VarianceInitializer in the same file